# Python - Dumb ques about nest loop in Python

Tags: python

I got a dumb question about nest loop in Python.

I just want to figure out why that second statement will follow the first statement to loop 5 times? Below is my loop code, hope someone can explain it to me. Thanks in advance! :)

```
for steps1 in range(5):
   print('@@@')
   print('@@@')
   for steps2 in range(4):
          print('###')
          print('###')
```

Comment: 4 times... not 5.

Comment: You want to figure out "why second statement will follow the first one"??? Is this for real?

Comment: which one is first statement and second statement? please give more explanation..

Comment: If the question is not clear, please vote to close?

Comment: Like I say, yeah, really that was a dump question. But the thing is, the "for steps1 in range(5):" that's the first loop statement I called, and next for statement is the second loop statement. So, why fist statement will loop 5 times, and second statement will follow up to loop 5 times? that's are my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should execute as follows: For each cycle of the outer loop, the inner loop executes 4 times. (If you struggle with that a pen & paper run simulation might be helpful). That being said your output should look somewhat like that:

```
@@@ //First outer cycle
@@@
### //First inner cycle
###
### //Second inner cycle
###
### //Third inner cycle
###
### //Fourth inner cycle
###
@@@ //Second outer cycle
@@@
...
```

This is how nested loops work in most languages. Since Python does not use brackets to determine function scopes you have to give great attention to intendation. If you would like your second `for` statement to run only 4 times, you would have to write your code like this:

```
for steps1 in range(5):
   print('@@@')
   print('@@@')
for steps2 in range(4):
   print('###')
   print('###')
```

Edit: More clarification

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Well, I known that my code execute result. I just wanna know why?

Comment: If you do not understand the question, you should not answer it.

Comment: The thing in Python is that (like meylo said in his answer) it builds scopes via intendation. So your code gets evaluated like I mentioned above. If you would like both loops to run independently from each other you would have to remove the intendation from the second loop. :)

Comment: Thanks Claudio, I get it.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score -2):

```html
for steps1 in range(5):
  print('@@@')
  print('@@@')
for steps2 in range(4):
  print('###')
  print('###')
```

the second statement is looping because of indentation

try this

Comment: Your answer has broken indentation.